# react native router flux delay issue

Tags: react-native, delay, react-native-router-flux

when i click on login btn then the btn takes delay of 5 sec then the dashboard apppeard , i donnt want this delay ... please help

here is my code

**loigin.js**

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnContainer} onPress={Actions.dashboard}>
                     <Text style={styles.btn}>LOG IN</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**Route.js**

```
                                    <Scene
                                    key="dashboard"
                                    component={Dashboard}
                                    title="Dashboard"
                                />
                                    <Scene
                                    key="login"
                                    component={Login}
                                    title="Login"
                                    hideNavBar
                                    initial

                                />
```

Comment: This issue could be related to what Dashboard is doing when it will mount/did mount. Can you share what the dashboard is trying to do when it mounts?

Comment: there is a simple just static content on dashboard .. no backend or api content just simple components on calling like accordion ,header, btn etc